# Consistency of projecting points onto an undistorted image

Tags: opencv, projection, camera-calibration, intrinsics, distortion

I want to project a point in 3D space into 2D image coordinates. I have the calibrated intrinsics and extrinsics of the camera I'm using. I have the camera matrix K and distortion coefficients D. However, I want the projected image coordinates to be of the undistorted image.

From my research, I found two ways to do this.

1. Use opencv's `getOptimalNewCameraMatrix` function to compute a new undistorted image's camera matrix K'. Then use this K' in opencv's `projectPoints` function, with the distortion parameters set to `0`, to get the projected point.
2. Use `projectPoints` function using the raw camera matrix K, along with the distortion coefficients D in this function and get the projected point.

Should the output of both methods match?

Comment: anything new? does it helps?

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is something missing in your thought.

Camera matrix K and dist. coefficent D are the parameters for make the undistortion (if your lens is distorting the image like in a fisheye). They are what is called intrinsic camera parameters.

If we change terms from computer vision to computer graphics, those parameters are the one you use for defining the frustum of the view, and, for example, they are used for getting the focal length of the camera.

But they are not enough to do the projection stuff.

For the projection, if you think in a computer graphics term (like opengl, for instance) you need to have the model-view-projection matrix. The model matrix is the matrix that specifies the position of the object in the world. The view matrix specifies the position of the camera, and the projection matrix specify the frustum (focal angle, perspective distortion, etc).

If you want to know how to transform the points of the model from 3d to 2d (or viceversa) you need the projection and the view matrixes (you have the model matrix because you have the 3d points from which you want to start). And in computer vision the view matrix is called estrinsic parameters.

So, you need the estrinsic parameters too, that are the position of the camera in the world. That is, for instance, those parameters are the `rvec` and `tvec` that `cv:: projectPoints` needs.

If you want to compute them, they are exactly the output of `cv::solvePnP` that do the opposite of what you want to do: from some known 3d points coupled with the known 2d projection on them on the camera screen, this function gives you the estrinsic parameters (from which you can get the view matrix for some opengl-opencv-augmented-reality-whatever application via `cv::Rodrigues`).

Last note: while the instrinsic parameters are fixed in all the pictures you shoot with a camera (while you don't change the focal length of course), the estrinisc parameters changes every time you move the camera for take a new picture from a different view point (that is: this changes the perspective point of view, so the 3D-2D projection you want to find)

Hope could help!